# unordered_map с кастомнымными функциями в классе

Tags: c++, классы, unordered-map

Мне надо хранить в классе соответствия между строками и числами. Порядок не важен, поэтому хочу использовать `std::unordered_map`, причём строки должны хэшироваться и сравниваться с помощью текущей локали через `std::collate::compare()` и `std::collate::hash()`.

Как лучше объявить эту структуру в классе, чтобы пользователь не видел реализацию? Проблемы в том, что 1) надо хранить экземпляр std::collate в классе или определять логически непринадлежащие классу функции; 2) надо знать bucket_count для определения структуры, т.к. этот параметр идет до функций хэша и сравнения.

Answer (score 0):

### В std::unordered_map уже есть требуемый функционал

Следуем [описанию](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) с cppreference , используем шаблонные параметры класса :

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int, std::collate::hash, std::collate::compare> my_map;
```

Проблем никаких нет, класс my_map хранит соответствие строки <---> числа, используя требуемую функцию хеширования и требуемую функцию сравнения.